# Can function parameters and local variables be used in constant expressions?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm new into programming and I started to learn about it using the book *Programming principles and practice using C++*. Today I'm here because I have some problems in understanding `constexpr` functions. In chapter 8 the author introduces them in some lines and a brief example using these words:

> A function represents a calculation, and sometimes we want to do a calculation at compile time. The reason to want a calculation evaluated by the compiler is usually to avoid having the same calculation done millions of times at run time.
>
> We convey our intend to have a function evaluated at compile time by declaring the function as a `constexpr` function. A `constepxr` function can be evaluated at compile time just if it is given constant expressions as arguments.
>
> ```
> constexpr double xscale = 10; // scaling factors 
> constexpr double yscale = 0.8; 
> constexpr Point scale(Point p) { return { xscale*p.x, yscale*p.y }; };
> ```
>
> Assume that point is a simple struct with members x and y representing 2D coordinates. Now, when we give `scale()` a `Point` argument, it returns a point with coordinates scaled according to the factors `xscale` and `yscale`. For example:
>
> ```
> void user(Point p1) {
>
>   Point p2{10,10}; 
>
>   Point p3 = scale(p1); 
>   Point p4 = scale(p2); // p4 == {100,8}
>
>   constexpr Point p5 = scale(p1); // error : scale(p1) is not a constant expression
>   constexpr Point p6 = scale(p2); // p6 == {100,8};
> ```

My question is: **Why we can use `p2` as an argument to `scale()`? Is `p2` considered a constant expression?** And if yes, why?

Can the  data members `x` and `y`  be considered constant expressions?

My book doesn't give too much information so I'm having some problems with this concept.

Comment: A `constexpr` function does *not* require that its arguments be constant expressions. This may be a common misconception. If you call such a function with non-constant arguments, the result is non-constant also. So basically, the phrase 'constexpr function' is a bit misleading. The *function* `foo` isn't `constexpr` - the *application* of the function, `foo(x,y)`, is constant if and only if `x` and `y` are constant

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, `constexpr` functions can be executed at compile time or run time depending on the context. It is guaranteed to execute at compile time only if all its parameters are `constexpr` and its result is used in a context requiring `constexpr` (e.g. assignment to `constexpr` value, template parameter, or, say, c-style array size). Otherwise, it is evaluated at runtime as any other function. So the `p3` and `p4` lines are executed at runtime, whereas `p5` gives an error because `scale(p1)` is not `constexpr`, and actually `p6` should also give you an error unless you add a `constexpr` to the definition of `p2`. See an example [here](https://ideone.com/bzL72l).

Comment: How `p6` can be executed on compile-time IF `p2` is not constant expression?

Comment: Huh, honestly, I'm super surprised that `p6` compiles. Even something as simple as `constexpr int plus2(int x) { return x + 2; }` `int i = 0; constexpr int j = plus2(i);` does not compile in either VS2015 or GCC 5.1. I'll edit my answer

Comment: `p6` is also doesn't compile by gcc/clang.

Comment: @NathanOliver The code does not compile, so his answer is incorrect. Mine also wasn't until the edit :)

Comment: @Rostislav Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Why we can use `p2` as an argument to `scale()`?**

Because `scale()` is written to accept anything which is a `Point` or is implicitly convertible to `Point`. In this case, `p2` is of type `Point`. Hence, it can be used as an argument to `scale()`.

**Is p2 considered a constant expression? And if yes, why?**

`p2` is actually declared as a local variable. When it is used as:

`constexpr Point p6 = scale(p2);`

its value is calculated at run time using the function call, and hence is an error. To make this work, remove the `constexpr` keyword. If you want it to work with `constexpr`, declare `p2` as `constexpr` first.

In the following case:

`constexpr Point p5 = scale(p1);`

`p1` is passed as an argument to `user()`, and can have any value, which can only be known at run-time, hence the error.

Comment: Can you give quote from standard about why `constexpr Point p6 = scale(p2);` should be compiled? Now, compiler-error will be.

Comment: @ForEveR Yes, it does not compile and it shouldn't. See my revised answer. Thanks for keeping a keen eye on this :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me, that it's gotcha in book. It looks like it should be

```
constexpr Point p2{10,10};
```

only in this case any modern compiler will not give [error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vIQHP2DZv3UA6qUU) on call

```
constexpr Point p6 = scale(p2); // p6 == {100,8};
```

that's because you are trying to initialize `constexpr` variable with result of function, which will be evaluated in runtime (if `p2` is not declared `constexpr`).

Comment: @NathanOliver In the case of `constexpr Point p2{10,10};` it `will not give` an error.